# How can I diff between 2 c++ files while preserving context?

Tags: diff

I had 2 files that were identical in the beginning, but I removed a bunch of functions in one of them for a cleanup.
However, I performed some modifications in the more complex file, and I'd like to integrate these modifications in the cleaned up file.

However, if I do a regular diff between the files, it's outputting many things, because in one of them, lots of functions have been removed, so lines are not synced anymore.

Is there a way to perform a diff based on context, where it will just give me a diff of functions in common between both files? Then I could easily create a patch to bring the modifications in functions from the 'messy' file to the cleaned up one without reintroducing the functions I deleted previously?

Thanks.

If I try to give an example it would be like:

```
Messy File:                                Clean File:

func1(int arg1, int arg2){                 func2(int arg1, int arg2){
 return arg1+arg2;                           return arg1*arg2;
}                                          }  

func2(int arg1, int arg2){
 return 2*arg1*arg2;
}
```

So in this example, I'd like to see that the return statement in func2 has changed, but not that func1 is missing, or comparing func1 and func2 in line-by-line diff.

Comment: For narrow screens: Both files are beside each other in the listing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I tried to resize my browser, and it just poped a scrolling bar. Maybe on smartphones, not sure.

Comment: You might try `diff -u` and filter out the results, for example remove blocks of lines starting with `-`, if before this block is a line starting with `@` and after it is a line starting with not `+`

Comment: Source Insight sorts the differences by symbol https://www.sourceinsight.com/doc/v4/userguide/Manual/Command_Reference/File_Compare.htm Understand could have similar functionality https://support.scitools.com/support/solutions/articles/70000583199-compare-two-understand-projects Those tools are often scriptable (e.g. to filter out complete new functions). Those are analyzers/editors/IDEs, which parse the source code to get a logical representation, which they use to provide all kinds of added tools to the programmers.

Comment: I tested Source Insight, but it seems it's also a line-by-line diff. I'm gonna check Understand.

Comment: The screenshot of Source Insight shows the differing symbols on the left, perhaps a code analysis has to be started first?

Comment: It shows symbols, but if you click on it, it will bring you to the function, but it will show you the diff with the code at the same line on the other file. Like in my example if I click on the symbol 'func2', it will bring me to the line, and show me it's empty in the clean file. But this is not what I want to see.  Ideally, it would show me a change happened in 'func2', and when I click on it, it will highlight that the return is different in both files (regardless of their position in the file).

Comment: I think Understand does what I need, still have to dig into it though. Really cool tool by the way, didn't know it, but it could have saved me lots of time on other tasks.

Comment: That could also be a suitable tool: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/CppSmartDifferencer.html?Home=CppTools:

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use that, but I couldn't start it (didn't try for very long though, maybe I will give it another try).

Comment: It is by Ira Baxter and her colleagues https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter

Answer (score 0):

You can further explore the results in the report using several methods:

Sort results — To sort the results by name, size, class, or difference summary, click the corresponding column header. For example, click the Class column header to sort by class type.

Load variable — To load the contents of a variable into the Variable Editor, click the name of that variable.

Load MAT-file — To load one of the MAT-files into the workspace, click the corresponding Load link at the bottom of the report.

Save HTML report — To save a copy of the report as an HTML file, go to the Comparison tab and click Save As > HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. You seem to talk about matlab, but I'm in C++.

Comment: visdiff lists under supported formats .cpp as *text based source file* https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/visdiff.html But can it detect C++ classes? Also in more complicated cases with #defines, #includes, #ifs, using directives and declarations, overloading, templates?

Comment: I tried visdiff, but it seems to be a line-by-line diff. It doesn't work with my example.